# 'BaseVariant' is deprecated, what is the alternative of BaseVariant?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

**'BaseVariant' has been deprecated.** I am using `BaseVariant` like this

```
  import com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant

  var bundleForVariant: (BaseVariant) -> Boolean = { variant ->
    if (bundleIn.getting(variant.name).isPresent) bundleIn.getting(variant.name).get()
    else if (bundleIn.getting(variant.buildType.name).isPresent)
        bundleIn.getting(variant.buildType.name).get()
    else variant.isRelease
  }

  var disableDevForVariant: (BaseVariant) -> Boolean = { variant ->
    variant.name in devDisabledInVariants.get() || variant.isRelease
  }
```

My question is what is the alternative of it?